# ubuntu 18 custom service does not load

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, service

ubuntu 18

I have created a custom service at /etc/systemd/system/mycustomservice.service

and enable it : sudo systemctl enable /etc/systemd/system/mycustomservice.service

but the service does not load at start up, the content is:

```
[Unit]
After=mysql.service

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/myuser/runupdate.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

I try to execute the file /home/myuser/runupdate.sh without any issue

the permission of

/home/myuser/runupdate.sh is -rwxr--r--
/etc/systemd/system/mycustomservice.service is -rw-rw-r--

Please advise, thank you!

Comment: Do you have #!/bin/bash at the top of the script?

Comment: I am kind of new to this, do you mean:
ExecStart=#!/bin/bash /home/myuser/runupdate.sh  ?

Comment: Systemd will need to know how to execute the script and what shell to use, hence #!/bun/bash or #!/bin/sh, Alternatively, you can use ExecStart=/bin/bash -c /home/myuser/runupdate.sh

Comment: you have solved the issue, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Systemd will need to know how to execute the script and what shell to use, hence there are two options Add:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

or

```
#!/bin/sh
```

to the top line of the script depending on the shell you  are using. Alternatively, you can use:

```
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c /home/myuser/runupdate.sh
```